# Django - How to pass a string value from the urlconf to feeds.py class

Tags: django

I'm struggling with something that I am sure has a very simple method, but I am not getting it right.  I am trying to pass a value from the urlconf to the feeds.py file.  What I am trying to do is generate specific feeds for comments on a page.

I have been reading the example in the documentation:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/syndication/

of how to use the get_object() method, but I cannot seem to pass the right values.

Here is what I have been trying.  In the url.py file:

```
    ('^post/(?P<sl>.*)/comment_feed/$', CommentFeed()),
```

And in the feeds.py file:

```
class CommentFeed(Feed):
def get_object(self, request, sl):
    return get_object_or_404(Post, ????)
```

And I keep getting a ValueError saying:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Test-1'

What is the right way to pass the object to the feeds CommnetFeed class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you were testing it with `post/Test-1/comment_feed/` - were you?

Django expects an integer as the post id. Give it a number as in `post/12/comment_feed/` and use `pk=sl` as done in the example given in the linked page.

```
return get_object_or_404(Post, pk=sl)
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it working.  Is there no way to pass a string.  What I was hoping was to have:
site.com/post/post_string
and then use
site.com/post/post_string/comment_feeds/

Is there no way to do that?

Comment: @Vernon You can do that if the primary key of `Post` is a string.